# I need to run program from cmd, using variable on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cmd

i need to run new-installed program from command prompt on windows 7 like it is posibble for notepad calc or some other windows-basic program... How i can do that? I tryed to use enviroment variables but i fell in stuck with it. Is there a way for something like this ?

Comment: Did you put correct way into environment variable?

Comment: either expand your %path% variable with the path to your program, or put a short batchfile (just starting your `\pathtoprogram\program`) into a folder in the current %path%

Comment: Your question is light on details  It's not even clear if you have tried `"c:\program files\program name\file.exe"`

Comment: did you use the command like start file.exe in command prompt

Comment: @panther : Yes i am sure. I put  name of program sublime in variable name : sublime and in variable value : C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\ then in PATH i adedd : something; %sublime%  but i still cant access to sublime via command prompt...

Comment: @Stephan i tryed that... Still does not works.

Comment: "still does not work" is not a good start for troubleshooting. Please edit your question to show, what you have tried, and what the output was.

Comment: Stephan i tryed that... Still does not works.                                 foxdrive i tryed it, but i want to use short variable for it, instead to write whole path...                                                KVK i tryed with start and without it.                             But when you enter into cmd and just type notepad, then notepad is open, i want to do same with sublime. Also when i type start sublime.exe windows shows erorr windows cannot find sublime.exe...

Comment: ... because `notepad` is in the path (in `C:\Windows\System32\` to be exact). See the second comment.

Comment: I just updated my Path in enviroment variables, then when i type sublime in cmd i got erorr from sublime : Unable to run package setup. Failed to load module. ImportErorr: No module named Package setup...

Answer (score 1):

try like this command

start c:\"Program Files"\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe

or you can use

"c:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"

quote must need for the the file/folder name which is having space

Comment: Are you sure? I'm using variant without quotes and it works me fine.

Comment: in another case "c:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"  it will work fine.can you show your command

Comment: I'm not a Win guru, I've only asked (without saying you have there a mistake). I have there `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick;C:\Program Files\SVN;...` - just dirs without exe files, without quotes. And it works me fine.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the comments to your question, you now managed to start your program from whereever you are by including it's path to the %path% variable.

Your new error "Unable to run package setup. Failed to load module. ImportErorr: No module named Package setup" comes from your program, which fails to load some of it's modules.

That's because it looks for them in the current working directory. (where you are, not where the program and it's modules are stored)

Create a short batchfile in the program's folder:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
start program.exe
```

Save it as "program.bat" (if you just enter "program", it will look first, if there is a .bat and starts that instead of an .exe with the same name).

The first line changes the current working directory to the file, where that .bat (and the program and it's modules) resides, the second line just starts the program itself.